# How can I combine two arrays for names and values to align side by side in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which I wish to combine so that name and value can be side by side.

I have this code:

```
 $mgl = array(
         '200101', 
         '200201', 
         '200202'
         );
    $mpro = array(
           'Current Account',
           'Regular Saving Account', 
           'Ileya Target' 
           );

      array_push($response, array(
                "glno"=>$mgl, 
                 "product"=>$mpro

                 ));

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=> $response));
```

When I viewed it it appeared this way:

> {"server_response":[{"glno":["200101","200201","200202"],"product":["Current
>   Account","Regular Saving Account","Ileya Target"]}]}

I want it in this format

```
{"server_response":[
 {"glno":"104100","product":"Micro Loans"}, 
 {"glno":"200101","product":"Current Account"}, 
 {"glno":"200201","product":"Regular Saving Account"}
]}
```

Comment: Where do the two arrays come from? And why is the question tagged with `mysql`?

Comment: I removed unrelated tag `mysql`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy enough using a `foreach` loop, using the first array as the start point and (as long as the arrays are the same length) just pick out the same value from the second array...

```
$response = [];
foreach ( $mgl as $key => $value )  {
    $response[] = ["glno" => $value, "product" => $mpro[$key]];
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=> $response));
```

gives..

```
{"server_response":[{"glno":"200101","product":"Current Account"},
    {"glno":"200201","product":"Regular Saving Account"},
    {"glno":"200202","product":"Ileya Target"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_combine(), this would be one solution of many in PHP.

```
<?php
$mgl=array("Micro Loans","Current Account","Ileya Target");
$mpro=array("104100","200101","200201");
$c=array_combine($mgl,$mpro);
print_r($c);
?>
```